sed command in bash to add XML content from one file to another
I have below file1.xml:
<loginIpRanges>
    <description>undefined</description>
    <endAddress>1.2.3.4</endAddress>
    <startAddress>1.2.3.0</startAddress>
</loginIpRanges>

I have below file2.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Profile xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <applicationVisibilities>
        <application>standard__S</application>
        <default>false</default>
        <visible>false</visible>
    </applicationVisibilities>
    <custom>true</custom>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ViewRoles</name>
    </userPermissions>
</Profile> 

I want to append all content of file1.xml to file2.xml but after custom tag and before userPermissions tag:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Profile xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <applicationVisibilities>
        <application>standard__S</application>
        <default>false</default>
        <visible>false</visible>
    </applicationVisibilities>
    <custom>true</custom>
    <loginIpRanges>
        <description>undefined</description>
        <endAddress>1.2.3.4</endAddress>
        <startAddress>1.2.3.0</startAddress>
    </loginIpRanges>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ViewRoles</name>
    </userPermissions>
</Profile> 

I need this solution added to Azure build pipeline in bash script. Already tried 'sed' command and I couldn't find this solution. Please can I get some help!!

When sed and XML appear in the same sentence, something is already wrong.  I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

sed and other text processors are not the right tool to manipulate structured data such as XML. Use a processor that knows about how data can (and must) be structured within XML-encoded documents.
xmlstarlet and xmllint have already been suggested, here's an approach using xq which comes with kislyuk/yq:
xq -x --xml-dtd '.Profile |= with_entries(
  select(.key != "custom") // (., (input | to_entries[]))
)' file2.xml file1.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Profile xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <applicationVisibilities>
    <application>standard__S</application>
    <default>false</default>
    <visible>false</visible>
  </applicationVisibilities>
  <custom>true</custom>
  <loginIpRanges>
    <description>undefined</description>
    <endAddress>1.2.3.4</endAddress>
    <startAddress>1.2.3.0</startAddress>
  </loginIpRanges>
  <userPermissions>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>ViewRoles</name>
  </userPermissions>
</Profile>


And this outputs nicely formatted XML, safely and dependably, without being fragile because of potential changes. ;)

With xmlstarlet and bash:
xmlstarlet edit -N x='http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata' \
  --append '//x:Profile/x:custom' --type elem -n 'loginIpRanges' \
  -v "$(xmlstarlet select --template --copy-of '//loginIpRanges/*' file1.xml)" file2.xml \
  | xmlstarlet unescape \
  | xmlstarlet format

Output:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Profile xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <applicationVisibilities>
    <application>standard__S</application>
    <default>false</default>
    <visible>false</visible>
  </applicationVisibilities>
  <custom>true</custom>
  <loginIpRanges>
    <description>undefined</description>
    <endAddress>1.2.3.4</endAddress>
    <startAddress>1.2.3.0</startAddress>
  </loginIpRanges>
  <userPermissions>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>ViewRoles</name>
  </userPermissions>
</Profile>


Cyrus' comment is absolutely right - as a general rule, sed and xml should make you squint and think twice.
But I get that sometimes it's the only option you have. If that's the case, make sure you and anyone you report to understand the risks. XML doesn't care much about whitespace, but sed certainly does, so a simple and perfectly valid change can and will often break a regex. YMMV, "you have been warned", etc.
That said, then
IF you can be reasonably certain of the format of your input, and that it won't significantly change, and quite a few other things, then you can write your sed script based on those assumptions. (Get startlet, seriously, but...)
$ sed '/<[/]custom>[[:space:]]*$/r file1.xml' file2.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Profile xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <applicationVisibilities>
        <application>standard__S</application>
        <default>false</default>
        <visible>false</visible>
    </applicationVisibilities>
    <custom>true</custom>
<loginIpRanges>
    <description>undefined</description>
    <endAddress>1.2.3.4</endAddress>
    <startAddress>1.2.3.0</startAddress>
</loginIpRanges>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ViewRoles</name>
    </userPermissions>
</Profile>

Notice this uses the existing formatting in the files, so the output isn't the nice indented format you showed above. XML won't care, and this makes for a reasonably simple one-liner. If formatting matters, don't use sed.
Also notice I added a check for the tag being at the end of a line, with possible whitespace. This is an example of why sed is fragile for this sort of thing. If someone adds another tag on the line behind </custom> it now gets ignored entirely.
A slightly better version would at least add some markers --
$ sed '/<[/]custom>[[:space:]]*$/{
  a <!-- programmatically inserted text BEGINS -->
  r file1.xml
  a <!-- programmatically inserted text ENDS -->
}' file2.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Profile xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <applicationVisibilities>
        <application>standard__S</application>
        <default>false</default>
        <visible>false</visible>
    </applicationVisibilities>
    <custom>true</custom>
<!-- programmatically inserted text BEGINS -->
<loginIpRanges>
    <description>undefined</description>
    <endAddress>1.2.3.4</endAddress>
    <startAddress>1.2.3.0</startAddress>
</loginIpRanges>
<!-- programmatically inserted text ENDS -->
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ViewRoles</name>
    </userPermissions>
</Profile>


If you find yourself on a system that doesn't have XML aware tools and you can't install them, here's how to do it using any awk:
$ awk '
    NR==FNR {
        new = (NR>1 ? new RS : "") $0
        next
    }
    /<userPermissions>/ && sub(/<custom>.*/,"",prev) {
        gsub(RS, "&"prev, new)
        print prev new
    }
    {
        print
        prev = $0
    }
' file1.xml file2.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Profile xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <applicationVisibilities>
        <application>standard__S</application>
        <default>false</default>
        <visible>false</visible>
    </applicationVisibilities>
    <custom>true</custom>
    <loginIpRanges>
        <description>undefined</description>
        <endAddress>1.2.3.4</endAddress>
        <startAddress>1.2.3.0</startAddress>
    </loginIpRanges>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ViewRoles</name>
    </userPermissions>
</Profile>

Note that, unlike the other current answers which just append after <custom> no matter which other tag follows it, the above is doing what was asked for in the question:

append all content of file1.xml to file2.xml but after custom tag and
before userPermissions tag:

so even if the input had a second <custom> tag, e.g. note the additional <custom> above <applicationVisibilities>:
$ cat file2.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Profile xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <custom>true</custom>
    <applicationVisibilities>
        <application>standard__S</application>
        <default>false</default>
        <visible>false</visible>
    </applicationVisibilities>
    <custom>true</custom>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ViewRoles</name>
    </userPermissions>
</Profile>

This script would still only put the file1.xml content in the desired location:
$ awk '
    NR==FNR {
        new = (NR>1 ? new RS : "") $0
        next
    }
    /<userPermissions>/ && sub(/<custom>.*/,"",prev) {
        gsub(RS, "&"prev, new)
        print prev new
    }
    {
        print
        prev = $0
    }
' file1.xml file2.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Profile xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <custom>true</custom>
    <applicationVisibilities>
        <application>standard__S</application>
        <default>false</default>
        <visible>false</visible>
    </applicationVisibilities>
    <custom>true</custom>
    <loginIpRanges>
        <description>undefined</description>
        <endAddress>1.2.3.4</endAddress>
        <startAddress>1.2.3.0</startAddress>
    </loginIpRanges>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ViewRoles</name>
    </userPermissions>
</Profile>

